# 78xx switching regulator question

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, linear-regulator

I would like to know how a 78xx series linear regulator can be used in a switching application. I have found a circuit that shows such a use, but I have trouble understanding how the circuit oscillates. Additionally, how would one choose the Zener diode?

[image]

Comment: Did you try LTSpice to simulate it's behavior?

Comment: Just a note that this is not a very good circuit to use in comparison with a modern switching regulator or even older ones. The switching frequency will be very low so the inductor is large, heavy and expensive.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321149/why-does-hysteretic-current-mode-control-have-variable-switching-frequency

Comment: Can be done **BUT** there are many many many better solutions available.

Answer (score 6):

The 470ohm and 0.5 ohm resistor to the ground terminal of the regulator give positive feedback. It operates as what is referred to as "Hysteretic mode".

Here is a link to an article on this type of converter [Hysteretic mode converters](http://www.powerelectronics.com/dc-dc-converters/hysteretic-mode-converters-demystified-part-1).

The zener diode would only be needed if the input voltage was above the max rating of the regulator. If so the zener needs to drop enough for the regulator voltage to be at a safe level.